# "Caution: Water Mo......." What is that word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I came across a screenshot of a film on the internet, and there is a caution plate on the tree in that scene. I couldn't read the last word on the plate:

> CAUTION: WATER MO..ASINS

What is that word?

[image]

Comment: moccasins.  A water moccasin is a type of snake.

Comment: [Water Mo*asin](http://www.onelook.com/?w=water+mo*asin&ls=a)

Comment: @MrLister The word "CAUTION" is reversed out of a red background. However that's a *lot* less clear than "moccasins", which seems perfectly legible. Perhaps it's just unexpected, which has led to the question: after all, what have American Indian slippers got to do with it?

Comment: I learned a new word +1

Comment: On an unrelated note, I think that it actually reads `WARNING:` instead of `DANGER:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DavidWallace mentioned, it's clearly *[water moccasins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agkistrodon_piscivorus)*.